# Привязка данных

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular2

Есть два div-a,  в одном находится редактируемый текст, в другом при выделении текста отображается выделенная часть. Необходимо при редактировании текста в первом диве редактировать его и во втором. Как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Так все-таки: jquery, angularjs или angular2?

Comment: Разница принципиальная, решения могут разительно отличаться

Comment: Я понимаю, что решения будут отличаться, но это не имеет значения для меня. Если Вы настаиваете, чтобы я назвала что-то конкретное, пусть будет jquery

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать вот так. Реализовал на textarea, а не на div'ах но смысл тот же.
На клике по первому получаем выделенную область или ничего, если выделения не было, вставляем во второй. Я на всякий случай дисейблю второй:)
У второго слушаем input, и новый текст вставляем между начальным и конечным сохранёнными индексами выделения.

```js
let textarea1 = document.querySelector("#area1"),
    textarea2 = document.querySelector("#area2"),
    selectionStart, selectionEnd, selectedText, beforeString, afterString;
    
function selectionHandler() {

    selectionStart = Math.min(textarea1.selectionStart, textarea1.selectionEnd);
    selectionEnd = Math.max(textarea1.selectionStart, textarea1.selectionEnd);
        
    if (selectionStart < selectionEnd) {
        selectedText = textarea1.value.substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
        textarea2.value = selectedText;
        textarea2.removeAttribute("disabled");
        beforeString = textarea1.value.slice(0, selectionStart);
        afterString = textarea1.value.slice(selectionEnd);
    }
    
    if (selectionStart === selectionEnd) {
        textarea2.setAttribute("disabled", true);
        textarea2.value = "";
    }
}

function changeHandler() {
    let newString = beforeString + textarea2.value + afterString;
        
    textarea1.value = newString;
}
    
textarea1.addEventListener("click", selectionHandler);
textarea2.addEventListener("input", changeHandler);
```

```css
.textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="area1" class="textarea"></textarea>
<textarea id="area2" class="textarea" disabled></textarea>
```